# Sistema de categorias e subcategorias/filhos infinitas

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou montando um sistema de categorias e subcategorias infinitas, simples de início. Encontrei um script na internet que atende aos requisitos, porém sua personalização e adaptação para meu projeto o tornou quase que inutilizável.

Estudei uma estrutura simples e adaptei o banco de dados e o script de cadastro corretamente, porém meu maior problema está sendo na parte da exibição.

*Utilizando como base os seguintes registros:* [image: IMAGEM]

Listando da maneira que adaptei (considerando incorreta) tenho algumas limitações pois quando se trata de filhos de subcategorias já filhos não são listados, necessito um script simples que faça tal procedimento e que seja de fácil personalização.

*Atualmente tenho o seguinte resultado:*
[image: Resultado]

**Meu script para listagem atual:**

```
<?php 
echo "<ul>";
$selCategorias2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cat WHERE cat_pai = ?");
$selCategorias2->execute(array(0));
while($rowCategoria2 = $selCategorias2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

    echo $rowCategoria2->cat_nome."<BR/>";

    $selFilhos = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cat WHERE cat_pai = ?");
    $selFilhos->execute(array($rowCategoria2->cat_id));
    while($rowFilho = $selFilhos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$rowFilho->cat_nome."<br/>";

        $selSubFilhos = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cat WHERE cat_pai = ?");
        $selSubFilhos->execute(array($rowFilho->cat_id));
        while($rowSubFilho = $selSubFilhos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$rowSubFilho->cat_nome."<br/>";
        endwhile;

    endwhile;

} //fecha while categoria raiz

echo "</ul>"; ?>
```

> Obs.: Sei que existem outras maneiras de espaçar a categoria além de "&nbsp" porém, neste caso é apenas para testes. 
>   O script no qual citei anteriormente utiliza FETCH_ASSOC em vez do FETCH_OBJ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Com essa estrutura de banco de dados, você pode usar uma função recursiva (uma função que chama a si própria) em PHP para extrair da árvore tantos níveis quanto houver no banco. A desvantagem disso é que serão necessárias múltiplas queries ao banco de dados.

Considerando seu código atual, o caminho mais curto seria uma função assim:

```
<?php 
function desceNaArvore($cat_pai = 0, $nivel = 0) {
    global $conn;
    $html = "";
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cat WHERE cat_pai = ?");
    $query->execute(array($cat_pai));
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):
        // Padding com espaços de acordo com o nível da categoria
        $html .= str_repeat("&nbsp;", $nivel * 4);
        // Nome da categoria
        $html .= $row->cat_nome . '<br>';
        // Filhos
        $html .= desceNaArvore($row->cat_id, $nivel + 1);
    endwhile;
    return $html;
}

echo desceNaArvore();
?>
```

#### Possíveis pontos de melhoria

- Use listas aninhadas em vez de indentação por espaços.
- Separe a lógica de obtenção dos dados da lógica de exibição. O ideal, em termos de organização do código, seria ter uma função recursiva para obter os dados (na forma de arrays aninhadas), e outra, também recursiva, para transformar os dados da array em HTML. Fica como sugestão de exercício, se quiser estudar mais sobre o assunto :)

Comment: Desta sua maneira ele apresenta erro na variável $conn, (Notice: Undefined variable: conn), porém a variável $conn esta setada corretamente, e também (Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object). Estranho. Cheguei a testar de outras maneiras para ver se estava se referindo devido a função ser pública, privada, etc. Mas não é isto...

Comment: Você está usando algum framework?

Comment: Não, somente o PHP em si.

Comment: @TiagoBoeing tente a versão atualizada, é só um problema de escopo.

Comment: Realmente funcionou, não havia tentado utilizar a variável $conn como global como você atualizou. É uma boa alternativa e atende as minhas necessidades.

Comment: Uma opção mais limpa seria passar o `$conn` como parâmetro à função, ou criar uma classe com tudo isso e acessar a conexão como `this->conn` de dentro da função/método @TiagoBoeing

Answer (score 7):

Em banco de dados esse tipo de resultado que você está buscando é com um tipo de query que é mais conhecida como [**Hierarchical query**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_query) (Query hierárquica ou query recursiva) com [**lista de adjacência**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_adjac%C3%AAncia).

Há bastante discussão sobre isso porque MySQL **não suporta** queries hierárquicas como outros DBMSs possuem como PostgreSQL e Oracle. Você encontra várias soluções malucas por ai criando extensas stored procedures, não muito eficiente.

A maneira mais simples de buscar os dados com uma lista de adjacência e com um **determinado** número de níveis é usando **[LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)**, ficaria mais simples e bem mais rápido que criando laço dentro de laço no **PHP** executando múltiplas queries, mas mesmo assim esse modelo é longe do ideal pois possui algumas limitações básicas.

Ficaria assim:

```
SELECT t1.cat_nome AS lev1, t2.cat_nome as lev2, t3.nome as lev3, t4.cat_nome as lev4
FROM cat AS t1
LEFT JOIN cat AS t2 ON t2.cat_pai = t1.cat_id
LEFT JOIN cat AS t3 ON t3.cat_pai = t2.cat_id
LEFT JOIN cat AS t4 ON t4.cat_pai = t3.cat_id
```

---

**Solução: Nested Model**

Caso você possa mudar a estrutura do seu banco de dados, eu recomendo você utilizar esse modelo, no mysql é a maneira mais fácil (leia-se possível) de buscar dados de maneira recursiva.

Há um artigo bastante detalhado que fala bastante sobre o modelo, a estrutura e como implementa-lo.

- [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

---

**Solução 2: Closure table**

Uma outra solução também viável que cria uma tabela adicional para armazenar a hierarquia dos registros.

- [Moving Subtrees in Closure Table Hierarchies](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/)

Comment: Eu não seria tão veemente na indicação dos *nested sets*. Dependendo do uso desejado, pode ser uma ótima ideia ou uma péssima ideia. Na minha experiência pessoal, depende muito do caso de uso.

Comment: +1 de qualquer maneira por documentar a variedade de soluções possíveis com MySQL puro.

Comment: Infelizmente não há solução perfeita para esse caso, por causa do próprio conceito de banco de dados relacional. Acabei adicionando uma outra solução além do nested model, tinha esquecido do closure table.

Comment: Quanto ao Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL, achei realmente muito interessante por trata apenas de consultas no SQL puro, porém em alguns casos torna-se uma maneira um  pouco limitada dependendo da quantidade de níveis desejada, mas é uma alterantiva viável de acordo com cada projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço ao @bfavaretto pela resposta que também ajudou muito e me fez replanejar o projeto por ser mais simples, porém quero compartilhar aqui também a maneira que eu havia solucionado anteriormente de receber as respostas.

No meu caso acabei adaptando um pouco para exibição de mais dados, você pode adaptar como quiser, neste caso basta modificar a função.

```
function imprimeMenuInfinito( array $menuTotal , $idPai = 0, $nivel = 0 )
{
        // abrimos a ul do menu principal
        echo str_repeat( "\t" , $nivel ),'<ul>',PHP_EOL;
        // itera o array de acordo com o idPai passado como parâmetro na função
        foreach( $menuTotal[$idPai] as $idMenu => $menuItem)
        {
                // imprime o item do menu
                echo str_repeat( "\t" , $nivel + 1 ),'<li>',"ID: ", $menuItem['id']," - ", $menuItem['name'], ' <a href=?id=', $menuItem['id'], '>Excluir</a> <a href=?id_cat=', $menuItem['id'],'>Adicionar subcategoria</a> <a href=?edita_cat=', $menuItem['id'], '>Editar</a>' , PHP_EOL;
                // se o menu desta interação tiver submenus, chama novamente a função
                if( isset( $menuTotal[$idMenu] ) ) imprimeMenuInfinito( $menuTotal , $idMenu , $nivel + 2);
                // fecha o li do item do menu
                echo str_repeat( "\t" , $nivel + 1 ),'</li>',PHP_EOL;
        }
        // fecha o ul do menu principal
        echo str_repeat( "\t" , $nivel ),'</ul>',PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Aqui exibimos a função:**

```
    $query = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM cat ORDER BY cat_nome ASC');
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $menuItens[$row->cat_pai][$row->cat_id] = array('name' => $row->cat_nome, 'pai' => $row->cat_pai, 'id' => $row->cat_id);
    }


    echo imprimeMenuInfinito($menuItens);
```

Considero a resposta do @bfavaretto ótima por ser simples e de fácil adaptação. Obrigado!

> Não esquecer o arquivo de conexão 
>   Ao adicionar novos atributos vindos do banco você deve enviá-los via array para a função, depois chamá-los em function.